# What is the point of a features.xml if I have to install the bundles in it manually?

Tags: osgi, bundle, karaf

I have a features.xml with a few bundles listed. But they all need to be installed apparently. So all that the features.xml does is gather the dependencies in one spot....

Unless I am horribly mistaken. In which case how does one resolve a situation where I have a lot of dependencies in features.xml and they are all not in any order. Right now I am going through the exercise of installing each bundle and starting them up one by one...

Tell me what I am doing wrong- of which there may be several things

Edit:
Features were generated by maven plugin.
When I install feature,  I get unresolved error

`Error executing command: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=myBundleApp; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.0.0.RC1,1.0.0.RC1]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=myBundleApp)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.0.0.RC1)(version<=1.0.0.RC1))" [caused by: Unable to resolve myBundleApp/1.0.0.RC1: missing requirement [myBundleApp/1.0.0.RC1] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server; type=osgi.bundle; version="[9.3.6.v20151106,9.3.6.v20151106]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server/9.3.6.v20151106: missing requirement [org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server/9.3.6.v20151106] osgi.extender; filter:="(osgi.extender=osgi.serviceloader.registrar)"]]`

But the feature.xml already has `<bundle>mvn:org.eclipse.jetty.websocket/websocket-server/9.3.6.v20151106</bundle>`

Comment: How does your feature look like and what is going wrong when you install it?

Comment: I usually use feature xml files together with developing a custom karaf distribution. Then it makes it easier as you just refer to the feature files rather than individual bundles.

Comment: Most likely your feature isn't complete, therefore you need to make sure that those bundle missing are also contained in your feature descriptor

Answer (score 4):

The point of `features.xml` is to define a repository of features that can be used to provision an OSGi application in [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/). In another words, it's purpose is exactly to **NOT have to install bundles manually**! As [documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_feature_and_resolver) states:

> When you install a feature, Apache Karaf installs all resources described in the feature. It means that it will automatically resolves and installs all bundles, configurations, and dependency features described in the feature.

That said, please keep in mind:

- this is Karaf specific functionality. It will not work with other OSGi containers
- before you can install a feature you need to make Karaf aware of the repository containing it. You can use `feature:repo-list` command to check what repos Karaf is aware of and `feature:repo-add` command to add repositories. Please see this [documentation](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_commands_3) for more details.
- URLs pointing to bundles, features, configurations, ... inside `features.xml` have to point to a reasoures Karaf [understands](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_artifacts_repositories_and_urls) and can access
- Features (much like bundles) need to be resolved before they be activated.

Comment: "Features"  is standard OSGi.  "features.xml" is Apache Karaf (and can be used elsewhere by installing the "Feature" bundles.  IBM Websphere/Liberty, on the other hand, typically uses "feature manifests": https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_feat_definition.html